# What is wrong with using the low level Datastore APIs

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Several sources recommend that I use standard interfaces such as JDO, JPO, and Objectify with the Datastore instead of the low-level APIs for "simplicity" reasons. Many code samples i've seen use these interfaces. But I don't find the low-level APIs all that complicated. Is there a better reason why I shouldn't use the low-level APIs besides simplicity?

Comment: This question will be closed as "opinion based", but I though I will give you an answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Reasons to use low-level API: (1) better performance, (2) fast instance start-up time, (3) precise control over your code, (4) fewer dependencies.

Reasons to use Objectify: (1) less boilerplate code, (2) more familiar approach for experienced Java developers.

Reasons to use JDO/JPA: compatibility with legacy code/software.